# запрос к базе MySQL c вложенным логическим отрицанием

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Доброго времени суток.
Есть три таблицы:

```
books (id, title)
users (id, first_name, last_name, age)
users_books (id, user_id, book_id)
```

В таблице `users_books` содержится информация о купленных пользователями книгах.
Необходимо выбрать список пользователей, которые не покупали книгу с определенным названием. Можно ли сделать оптимальнее, чем сделал я?

Мой запрос:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT users.first_name, 
           users.last_name, 
           users.id 
      FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_books ON users.id = users_books.user_id 
WHERE users_books.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id 
                                    FROM users_books
                                   WHERE users_books.book_id = (SELECT id 
                                                                  FROM books 
                                                                 WHERE title = "Book")) 
  GROUP BY users_books.user_id
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать один вложенный запрос:

```
SELECT id, 
       first_name, 
       last_name
  FROM users 
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ub.user_id
                    FROM books b
               LEFT JOIN users_books ub ON b.id = ub.book_id
                   WHERE b.title = 'Book'
                     AND ub.id IS NOT NULL)
```

По сути, то же, что в исходном запросе. Вложенные запросы объединены левым джойном => важно убедиться, что в выборку не попали книги, которые вообще никто не купил (ub.id IS NOT NULL).

DISTINCT во вложенном запросе на случай, если вдруг возможна ситуация, когда один пользователь несколько раз купил одну книгу.

Снаружи DISTINCT не нужен.

**UPD.** Улучшенный по рекомендациям [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) запрос:

```
SELECT id, 
       first_name, 
       last_name
  FROM users 
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ub.user_id
                    FROM books b
                    JOIN users_books ub ON b.id = ub.book_id
                   WHERE b.title = 'Book')
```

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за комментарий. Поправил ответ. И ведь сколько раз использовал джойны, а до сих пор есть куда расти. Круто.